# How to compute the formula of $S_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$S_1$=a, $S_2$=b, $S_n$=|$S_{n-1}$-$S_{n-2}$|(n $\ge$3). Can I compute the formula of $S_n$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is S ? because if constant , Sn-1 does'nt mean anything

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam: He has defined a sequence (subscripts).

Comment: oh ok . sorry it was a miss.

Comment: is it not that what he has itself is a formula ?

Comment: @Harish: The OP is looking for a closed form, rather than a recursive one.

Comment: Essentially you get the sequence you would get if you ran Euclid's Algorithm, except you get a bunch of padded terms.

Answer (score 1):

If $b=qa+r$, then the sequence is

$a,b, (q-1)a+r, a, (q-2)a+r, (q-3)a+r, a, (q-4)a+r, (q-5)a+r, a, \dots$

eventually you get to two consecutive terms that are $a, r$ or $r,a$, and you repeat.  Thus you basically get the sequence from Euclid's Algorithm.  That is, the sequence eventually ends with

$gcd(a,b), gcd(a,b), 0,gcd(a,b), gcd(a,b), 0, \dots$

Comment: +1 for figuring this much out. But I'm not sure that you can assume that $a$ and $b$ are integers :-)

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are not integers, then the answer is still the same by working (mod $a$).  Except, now the sequence will not necessarily end by becoming periodic.  I assumed that $a$ and $b$ were integers, else there is not really hope for a *closed form*.  My answer is basically closed form if one cared enough to write it out.